# Kotlin Spring Boot testing endpoints and service layer with repository layer mocked

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, mocking

In order to test endpoints I'm using JUnit with `SpringRunner` and `@WebMvcTest`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(UserEndpoints::class)
class UserEndpointsTest {
}
```

`UserEndpoints` depends on `UserSevice`

`UserService` depends on `UserRepository`

I would to mock `UserRepository` in order to test `UserEndpoints`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(UserEndpoints::class)
class UserEndpointsTest2 {

    @Autowired
    private val mockMvc:MockMvc?=null

    @MockBean
    private val userRepository:UserRepository?=null

    @InjectMocks
    private var userService:UserService?=null

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        initMocks(this)

        Mockito.`when`(userRepository !!.findById(eq("1")))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(users().get(0)))

        Mockito.`when`(userRepository.findById(eq("2"))).thenReturn(Optional.of(users().get(1)))
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetUser() {
        this.mockMvc!!.perform(get("/user").param("id", "2"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.username").value(Matchers.equalTo("username1")))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.remaining_requests").value(Matchers.equalTo(101)))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.type").value(Matchers.equalTo("USER")))
    }

    fun users(): List<User> {
        val user1 = User("1", "username", "password", "123", 100, UserType.BETA)
        val user2 = User("2", "username1", "password1", "1234", 101, UserType.USER)
        return arrayListOf<User>(user1, user2)
    }

    private fun <T> any(type: Class<T>): T {
        Mockito.any(type)
        return null as T
    }
}
```

The problem is that is not working because there is no `repositoryBean` to be injected into `userService` bean.

It fails with

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'userService' of type 'class service.UserService'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Parameter specified as non-null is null: method service.UserService.<init>, parameter userRepository
```

What is the correct way of mocking repository layer?

Answer (score 0):

So first, if this a web layer/controller test you should mock `UserSevice` not user repository. If this is a test for `UserSevice` you do not need web environment. Second I think your code is really verbose for declaring types as nullable I would use kotlin [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables) created specifically for these cases.

Said that what I usually do is create a nested `@Configuration` class which contains my beans declaration explicitly.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@WebMvcTest(UserEndpoints::class)
@Import(TestConfig::class)
class UserEndpointsTest {
}
```

```
@Configuration
class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    fun userRepository(): UserRepository = mock(UserRepository.class)

    @Bean
    fun userService(UserRepository userRepo): UserService = UserService(userRepo)
}
```

Then you can inject your beans with simple `@Autowired` (no need to mix both spring and mockito annotations)